# Adding multiple paths to eslint-plugin-import pattern

Tags: eslint, eslint-plugin-import

I am looking to use eslint to force my imports to be in a standard order.

I have got this working, however it leads to a long eslint file as I have many different paths I have TypeScript aliases set up with that I want the eslint rules to exclude when sorting the external packages.

I have it working like this:

```
"import/order": [
  "error",
  {
    "groups": ["builtin", "external", "internal"],
    "pathGroups": [
      {
        "pattern": "react*",
        "group": "external",
        "position": "before"
      },
      {
        "pattern": "Components/**",
        "group": "internal"
      },
      {
        "pattern": "Constants/**",
        "group": "internal"
      }
      ... more patterns here
    ],
    "pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes": ["react", "internal"],
    "alphabetize": {
      "order": "asc",
      "caseInsensitive": true
    }
  }
],
```

I was wondering if there was a way to group the patterns, so I could do something more like this:

```
"import/order": [
  "error",
  {
    "groups": ["builtin", "external", "internal"],
    "pathGroups": [
      {
        "pattern": "react*",
        "group": "external",
        "position": "before"
      },
      {
        "pattern": "Components/**|Constants/**|AnotherAlias/**|AnotherAlias/**",
        "group": "internal"
      }
    ],
    "pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes": ["react", "internal"],
    "alphabetize": {
      "order": "asc",
      "caseInsensitive": true
    }
  }
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is a [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) pattern. As you can see using [this](https://globster.xyz/) (I think) unofficial tester, to make the pattern match a string among a set, you should use the set operator:

```
{string1,string2,string3}
```

In your case, then, you can write like this

```js
//...
"pathGroups": [
      {
        "pattern": "react*",
        "group": "external",
        "position": "before"
      },
      {
        "pattern": "{Components,ConstantsAnotherAlias,AnotherAlias}/**",
        "group": "internal"
      }
    ],
//...
```

I'm not sure that this would fix your issue, though.
I solved it by properly setting the eslint setting `import/internal-regex`.
This setting tells eslint, and then the plugin (as you can see [here](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/328064abc707d3289772a8a29da5783c6dc345f6/src/core/importType.js#LL17C71-L17C71)), how to tell if an import is internal.
So you could set it:

```js
//...
"settings": {
  "import/internal-regex": "(Components|Constants|AnotherAlias|AnotherAlias)(/.+)?"
}
//...
```